# AJAX POST request with json data to a spring controller returns status 405

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf, spring-restcontroller

I'm using spring-thymeleaf to return a page with an object as a spring attribute. And then making an AJAX POST request to a spring controller. Some how im getting

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
Request method 'GET' not supported
```

error which is strange im not doing any GET request.

This is the first spring controller and then setting the Param object and pass to the view.

```
    @RequestMapping("/listing")
    public String privateReport(Principal principal, HttpServletRequest request, Model model) throws Exception { 
    Param param = new Param();
        param.setStartDate(startDate);
        param.setEndDate(endDate);
        model.addAttribute("params", param);

        return "listing-report";
    }
```

The view which includes a datatable and doing an AJAX post to get the data by passing the Param as a json object listing-report.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

    <head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
       <div class="container">
         <h2>Private Corporate Patient Listing Report</h2>
       </div>
    <div class="container" style="margin-top: 25px;">
    <table id="casesTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered nowrap">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Case Number</th>
            <th>Patient Name</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Charge Amt</th>
            <th>Clinic</th>
            <th>Doctor</th>
            <th>Diagnosis</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
       </table>
     </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script th:inline="javascript">
      var params = [[${params}]];

      $('#reportsTable').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bFilter": false,
        "ajax": {
            type : "POST",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            url : "/report/listing-data",
            data: JSON.stringify(params),
            dataSrc: ''
        },
     "columns": [
            {"data": "caseStartDate"},
            {"data": "caseNumber"},
            {"data": "patientName"},
            {"data": "address"}
        ]
      });

    </script>

    </body>

    </html>
```

The spring REST controller that returns data :

```
     @RequestMapping(value = "/report/listing-data", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity privateReportData(@RequestParam("page") int page,
                                            @RequestParam("size") int size,
                                            @RequestBody Param param) {

        param.setPage(page);
        param.setSize(size);
        logger.info("Requesting table data " + param);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(reportDataService.getView(param));
    }
```

The Param model :

```
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @ToString
    public class Param extends CommonParams {

      @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
      private LocalDate startDate;
      @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
   }
```

CommonParams model :

```
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @ToString
    public class CommonParams {

      private int page;
      private int size;
    }
```

Where would i have gone possibly wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add the page from where `/listing` is called ?

Comment: which DataTable are you using?

Comment: @AhmetOZKESEK updated the question with html code

Comment: Can you add consumes attribute as 'application/json' in RequestMapping and try.

Comment: @AnilNivargi tried. no luck